# Get information in sub-tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve information from a site by web scraping. The information I need is found in sub-tabs, but I'm not able to get it

```
<div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 House
 3
 pièces,                                                                                                         
74 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 New York (11111)
 </cite>
 </div>
</div>,
 <div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 Appartement
 3
 pièces,                                                                                                         
64 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 Los Angeles (22222)
 </cite>
 </div>
 <div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 House
 4
 pièces,                                                                                                         
81 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 Chicago (33333)
 </cite>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to get the ad and the city. I tried:

```
#BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#to get: House 3 pièces, 74 m²
ad = [ad.get_text() for ad in soup.find_all("span", class_='ergov3-txtannonce')]  

#to get cities       
cities = [city.get_text() for city in soup.find_all("cite", class_='ergov3-txtannonce')]
```

My output:

```
[]
[]
```

Good output:

```
["House 3 pièces, 74 m²", "Appartement 3 pièces, 64 m²", "House 4 pièces, 81 m²"]                                                                                                       
["New York (11111)", "Los Angeles (22222)", "Chicago (33333)"]
```

Comment: Wild guess because I don't work with bs often: Span doesn't have the said class, its parent does. What I'd do: 1) Use xpath to find div with class with span children. Or 2) Find divs in that way (literally what you do but div) and then find children inside that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you `soup` contains the provided `HTML` select the elements that holds your information and iterate over the `ResultSet` to scrape the information. avoid multiple lists, try to scrape all information in one go and save it in a more structured way:

```
...
data = []

for e in soup.select('.ergov3-txtannonce'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.span.get_text(strip=True),
        'city':e.cite.get_text(strip=True)
    })
...
```

---

**Note:** *If the elements are not present in your soup, content of website may provided dynamically by `JavaScript` - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 House 3 pièces, 74 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 New York (11111)
 </cite>
 </div>
</div>,
 <div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 Appartement 3 pièces, 64 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 Los Angeles (22222)
 </cite>
 </div>
 <div class="ergov3-txtannonce">
 <div class="ergov3-h3"><span>
 House 4 pièces, 81 m²
 </span>
 <cite>
 Chicago (33333)
 </cite>
 </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('.ergov3-txtannonce'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.span.get_text(strip=True),
        'city':e.cite.get_text(strip=True)
    })

data
```

###### Output

```
[{'title': 'House 3 pièces, 74 m²', 'city': 'New York (11111)'},
 {'title': 'Appartement 3 pièces, 64 m²', 'city': 'Los Angeles (22222)'},
 {'title': 'House 4 pièces, 81 m²', 'city': 'Chicago (33333)'}]
```